# Remove the loess smooth standard error gray area (or apply alpha to it)

Tags: r, plot, ggpairs

The following code returns the plot below.
Is there a way to remove the standard error gray area or apply alpha to it so it's not so saturated? Especially the case where many lines are plotted this can interfere in the visualization. Thanks!

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
ggpairs(swiss[1:3], 
        lower=list(continuous=wrap("smooth", colour="blue")),
        diag=list(continuous=wrap("barDiag", fill="blue")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `se = F` , like in `ggplot2::geom_smooth()`:

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
ggpairs(swiss[1:3], 
        lower=list(continuous=wrap("smooth", colour="blue", se = F)),
        diag=list(continuous=wrap("barDiag", fill="blue")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And how about changing the alpha to make it less visible? Is that possible?

Comment: You're welcome. AFAIK it should not possible straightforwardly. Probably rewriting a bit the function you can put manually it. If you put alpha with se=T, it's going to be work on the dots.